# Highcharts-3D not working with electon app

Tags: javascript, highcharts, electron

I ran into this issue where highcharts-3D is not rendering properly in electron app window.The chart is shown however in 2D and not in 3D.

In order to re-check I ran the code in chrome browser without using the electron cli command.This time it worked with correct 3D rendering.

Just got to think, does electron has issues with highcharts 3D rendering ?

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo on the jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0):

> Just got to think, does electron has issues with highcharts 3D rendering ?

No it is not a bug, it works very well by importing modules js since node! (As in the [example given](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/install-from-npm) on the official website)

Exemple in electron:

[image: HighChart + Electron]
[image]